# I want to do a cron-job with the help of docker (Aipine) and the whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, cron

## Aasumption

I m using `docker-compose` and wanted to use the `whenever gem` to do a `cron` process that deletes at a certain time in `Rails`, but upon research I found that I have to install and run `cron` in `docker`. So I looked into it, but I can't find any information about `Alpine` regarding cron processing in Rails. Can an
yone tell me how to do this?

## What we have achieved

I want to execute a specific process once a day.

## Code

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1-alpine

ARG WORKDIR

ENV RUNTIME_PACKAGES="linux-headers libxml2-dev make gcc libc-dev nodejs tzdata postgresql-dev postgresql git" \
    DEV_PACKAGES="build-base curl-dev" \
    HOME=/${WORKDIR} \
    LANG=C.UTF-8 \
    TZ=Asia/Tokyo

RUN echo ${HOME}

WORKDIR ${HOME}

COPY Gemfile* ./

RUN apk update && \ 
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache ${RUNTIME_PACKAGES} && \
    apk add --virtual build-dependencies --no-cache ${DEV_PACKAGES} && \
    bundle install -j4 && \
    apk del build-dependencies

COPY . .

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Here is my Docker Compose file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.3-alpine
    environment:
      TZ: UTC
      PGTZ: UTC
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - ./api/tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  

  api:
    build:
      context: ./api
      args:
        WORKDIR: $WORKDIR
    command: /bin/sh -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: $POSTGRES_PASSWORD
      API_DOMAIN: "localhost:$FRONT_PORT"
      APP_URL: "http://localhost:$API_PORT"
    volumes:
      - ./api:/$WORKDIR
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "$API_PORT:$CONTAINER_PORT"
  mailcatcher:
    image: schickling/mailcatcher
    ports:
      - "1080:1080"
      - "1025:1025"

  front:
    build:
      context: ./front
      args:
        WORKDIR: $WORKDIR
        CONTAINER_PORT: $CONTAINER_PORT
        API_URL: "http://localhost:$API_PORT"
    command: yarn run dev
    volumes:
      - ./front:/$WORKDIR
    ports:
      - "$FRONT_PORT:$CONTAINER_PORT"
    depends_on:
      - api
```

Actual processing

/config/schedule.rb

```rb
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/environment")
ENV.each { |k, v| env(k, v) } 

set :output, "#{Rails.root}/log/cron.log"
set :environment, :development

every 1.days do
  runner "User.guest_reset"
end
```

## What we tried

I did a lot of research and found a lot of information on using `cron` with `apt`, but could not find any information on using `apk`.

Comment: `cron` is already a part of alpine, you dont have to install it separately

Comment: You could also use the gem Arask to keep things alot cleaner and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Separate `cron` into another service in your `docker-compose.yml` by using the same image as your rails app image (which built by Dockerfile). Then run `cron` and `whenever --update-crontab` in the command.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: myapp
    depends_on:
      - 'db'
    build:
      context: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && 
      bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - ".:/myapp"

  cron:
    image: myapp
    command: bash -c "touch log/cron.log && cron && whenever --update-crontab &&
      crontab -l && tail -f log/cron.log"
    volumes:
      - '.:/myapp'

  db:
    image: postgres:13
    ports: # 127.0.0.1 to only expose the port to loopback
      - '127.0.0.1:5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - 'postgres_dev:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:3.0.1

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y postgresql-client cron vim \
  && mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp

ENV BUNDLE_WITHOUT=development:test

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5

COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install --check-files --production
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added the docker-compose file.
For the ``myapp`` part of ``image``, do I just bring the appropriate image from docker hub?"

Comment: That is just to name your image and thus can be referenced from your cron service to make sure it will use the same image.

Comment: I based my image from ruby image, so i need to apt-get install cron in Dockerfile.

Comment: I am using alpine and cannot use apt-get. does that mean I need to change from alpine?

Comment: The equivalent of apt or apt-get in Alpine is apk. but isn't cron already included in alpine image?

Comment: Yes, ``alpine`` seems to include ``cron``, so no installation is required. I guess I am not knowledgeable enough to understand your useful advice.
Do you mean that I need to create a separate ``Docker File`` to run ``cron`` as you answered, or do I need to rewrite the ``ruby:2.7.1-alpine`` that I created with ``alpine``?

Comment: My advice is since we are using Docker to create micro-services, so why not separate cron into another service. Not in your rails app container.